# VSCode can't connect to WSL2 after enabling Systemd feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

In the beginning, I want to automatically start an SSH server when WSL2 boots up. I’ve found from others’ answers that Systemd can meet my requirements. So, I enabled the Systemd feature by setting systemd = true in the wsl.conf file. And then my vscode can't connect to Debian. There’s an ‘Opening Remote…’ message at the bottom left of the screen. I’m not sure what’s happening. Could there be a service that I forgot to start?

- OS: Windows 11
- WSL Version: 2.0.14.0
- Visual Studio Code Version: 1.86.2
- WSL Extension Version: v0.86.0
- Distribution: Debian

Once I disable the Systemd feature, VSCode is able to connect to Debian again.